# How can I stop the execution of another line until it has completed its execution of its current function

Tags: node.js, async-await, backend

Here is my code :

```
var data;
function fetch_details(){
    db.any({   //to get the operator id and operator name
        text: `select operator_id,op_fName from operators where operator_id='OPER123';`,
        values: [],
        rowMode: "array",
    })
   .then((rows) => {
     data=rows;   
     console.log(data)
    }
}
fetch_details()   //function call
console.log(data);  //I am getting undefined
```

I need that data after fetching it from the database, not for printing it but I Want to export it and use it another file.
I also tried using **async-await** but i didn't get to know how to use it properly.
Don't bother about db
I have imported it from another file, everything is working fine.
Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an async-await version to resolve the issue:

```js
var data;
async function fetch_details() {
  data = await db.any({
    text: `select operator_id,op_fName from operators where operator_id='OPER123';`,
    values: [],
    rowMode: 'array',
  });
}
await fetch_details();
console.log(data);
```

In case the code shared by you is in another function:

```
function(){
   <your snippet>
}
```

The outer function would also need to have the async keyword as show for fetch_details.

In case you're looking to avoid that, you can also do the following:

```js
var data;
async function fetch_details() {
  data = await db.any({
    text: `select operator_id,op_fName from operators where operator_id='OPER123';`,
    values: [],
    rowMode: 'array',
  });
}
fetch_details().then(function() {
  console.log(data);
  // further processing and use of data
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much....I used the last one